# Displaying image on Thymeleaf from List of objects returned via MySQL/Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, thymeleaf

I'm attempting to make a portfolio website that I can edit all portfolio items utilizing my own REST api. With that in mind, I have stored 8 images in my database under the Skills table that has a foreign key of user_id.

Whenever I go to display the Thymeleaf page of my skills, instead of getting an image I receive an unloaded image and this shows in my view page source "[B@6e8a976f".

I have tried converting it to Base64 but keep receiving a nullpointer exception.

User.java

```
@Entity
public class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long id;

  private String firstName;

  private String lastName;

  private String username;

  private String email;

  private String phoneNumber;


  @OneToOne
  private Demographic demographic;

  @OneToOne
  private Resume resume;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JsonIgnore
  private List<Skills> userSkills;

  public User() {
  }
  ... getters/setters
}
```

Skills.java

```
@Entity
public class Skills {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long id;

  private String techName;
  private byte[] logo;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
  private User user   ;

  public Skills() {
  }
  ... getters/setters
}
```

HomeController

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {

  @Autowired
  private UserService userService;

  @Autowired
  private SkillsService skillsService;


  @RequestMapping("/home")
  public String showHome() {
      return "index";
  }

  @RequestMapping("/portfolio")
  public String showPortfolio() {
      return "portfolio";
  }

  @GetMapping(value = "/technology")
  public String technologyList(Model theModel, Skills skills) {
      User user = userService.findByUsername("wmangram");
      List<Skills> userSkillsList = skillsService.findSkillList("wmangram");

      theModel.addAttribute("userSkills", userSkillsList);

      return "technology";
  }

  @RequestMapping("/resume")
  public String showResume() {
      return "resume";
  }

}
```

skills.html

```
<tbody>                                      
  <tr th:if="${userSkills.empty}">                                           
     <td colspan="2"> No Skills Available </td>                                      
  </tr>                                      
  <tr th:each="skills : ${userSkills}">                                          
     <td><span th:text="${skills.techName}"></span></td>                                             
     <td><img th:src="${skills.logo}"/></span></td>                                      
  </tr>                                  
</tbody>
```

UPDATE

```
@GetMapping(value = "/technology")
public String technologyList(Model theModel, Skills skills) throws IOException {
    User user = userService.findByUsername("wmangram");
    List<Skills> userSkillsList = skillsService.findSkillList("wmangram");

    byte[] encodeBase64 = Base64.encodeBase64String(skillsService.findLogos());
    String base64Encoded = new String(encodeBase64, "UTF-8");
    ModelAndView.addObject("userImage", base64Encoded );

    theModel.addAttribute("userSkills", userSkillsList);

    return "technology";
}
```

SkillService.java

```
public interface SkillsService {
  List<Skills> findSkillList(String wmangram);

  byte[] findLogos();


}
```

SkillServiceImpl.java

```
public byte[] findLogos() {
    return skillsDao.findLogos();
}
```

CustomerSkillsDao.java

```
@Repository
public interface CustomSkillsDao {

@Query("SELECT logo from portfolio.skills")
byte[] findLogos();
}
```

Update 2
HomeController

```
List<byte[]> logo = skillsService.findLogos();
    List<String> base64List = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < logo.size(); i++) {
        byte[] encodeBase64 = Base64.encodeBase64(logo.get(i));
        String base64Encoded = new String(encodeBase64, "UTF-8");
        base64List.add(base64Encoded);
    }

    theModel.addAttribute("userSkills", userSkillsList);
    for (int j = 0; j < base64List.size(); j++) {
        theModel.addAttribute("userImage", base64List.get(j));
        System.out.println("\\\nThis is the base64 called for: " + base64List.get(j));
    }
// All the base64List.get(j) in the sysout prints different base64 values so 
// I wouldn't imagine that this should be causing an issue 
// unless there is something I'm missing
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: This method is suitable if your image is small otherwise expose it on an endpoint.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/image/{imageid}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String image(Model model,@PathVariable int imageid) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {            
        String encodeBase64 = convertBinImageToString(imagedao.getObject(imageid).getImage()); 
        String photoencodeBase64 = new String(encodeBase64);
        model.addAttribute("image", photoencodeBase64);
        return "imageview"; 
    }

    public static String convertBinImageToString(byte[] binImage) {
        if(binImage!=null && binImage.length>0) {
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(binImage);
        }
        else
            return "";
    }
```

On the JSP Page:
`<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,${image}" />`

Comment: I'm confused on this, I've seen the answer provided but it's not clear where that piece of code should go.

Should it be in my controller and I make another service - dao to call for the logos specifically? Currently the code I have is calling the skill name and logos together

Thank you for reaching out also!

Comment: Controller where you are rendering the view. Just the way you'd send other typical object to the view.

Comment: Thank you, I went ahead and did that and have made a query to pull all logos from the database in the Skills table however the code is saying that it's returning as a String and not byte[].

I'll add the changes in the OP

Comment: Okay so I figure out the error I had, got that resolved. So to recap, I ended up making a List<byte[]> so that my query could store all of the logos. I'm a little lost on how to make it encode a list of bytes however

Comment: Will making a list of `base64Encoded` from list of `List<byte[]>` do the job? And than you simply iterate through the list on the view.

Comment: Hey devyJava, thank you for providing so much assistance with this! Having a better understanding as we go along, however, still running into the images not displaying. I'll update the OP with the code I've added to the HomeController.

Comment: @WillieMangram sure no problem, do update the code and lets see what the issue is. Make sure you have the image before you send it off to the front page.

Comment: I figured it out @devyJava, turned out that the Thymeleaf code needed to be <img th:src="|data:image/jpg;base64,${userImages[index]}|" /> I ended up iterating the list using the th:each="userImage, iter : ${userImages}"> and replacing ${userImages[index] with ${userImage} in the img tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it to `base64` if it isn't already.

After converting below should work.

`<img src="data:image/jpg;base64, [your byte array]">`